# How to launch Android Studio using Terminal

Tags: command-line, android, android-studio

I've just installed Android Studio. After installing, I forgot to add in the launcher. I restarted the system.

Now I want to launch Android Studio from Terminal. I've tried everything but didn't work.

Answer (score 14):

`cd` into the directory where you unzipped the android studio installer zip file. The folder is named **android-studio**. It could be in your `~/Downloads` folder if you downloaded it from the internet. Now `cd` into the **bin** folder and run the **studio.sh** file

```
./studio.sh
```

Comment: can you please give me the commands.i am new on ubuntu

Comment: if your extracted zip file path is PATH_TO_ZIP_FILE, then type `PATH_TO_ZIP_FILE/android-studio/bin/studio.sh` .  For example if the android-studio folder is in downloads directory type  `$HOME/Downloads/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`

Answer (score 6):

On ubuntu it is `/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`

You can open terminal by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

just run this command into your terminal

cd /usr/local/android-studio/bin

/usr/local/android-studio/bin$ ./studio.sh

Answer (score 2):

**option 1 :** set path alias in bashrc file by echo command

```
echo "alias android='/usr/local/android-studio/bin/studio.sh'" >> ~/.bashrc
source .bashrc
```

**option 2 :** set path alias by opening bashrc file.

open bashrc file on nano editor

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

paste this text in bashrc file

```
alias android='/usr/local/android-studio/bin/studio.sh'
```

**ctrl + S** to save file . **Ctrl + X** to exit.

finally source it

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

To run android studio, you need to type only

```
android
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use terminal to start a program then you should be knowing the command to be written in terminal. To know the command in Kubuntu I use the Kmenuedit. In kmenuedit find that program and that program's details there will be a field named command there you will find text to be written in terminal. Another option is to check system monitor program that also has a column named command. So you can check running instances of programs and command.

Answer (score 0):

Go to android studio folder in your system then
 1. Press right click of mouse and open terminal 
 2. wright `./studio.sh` and press enter
 3. it would open your android emulator in ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reduce job by setting an environment variable

```
echo "alias android_studio=/usr/local/android-studio/bin/studio.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
source .bashrc
```

Whenever want to open Android Studio just fire command

```
android_studio
```

I hope this will reduce your work.

Good luck..!

Answer (score 0):

> Launching Android Studio using Terminal with SUDO privileges

1. Open terminal `(ctrl + alt + t)`
2. Type `sudo su` command then enters your password.
3. Type `cd /opt/android-studio/bin`
4. Run Android studio using `sh ./studio.sh`